# Как собрать словари в столбце DataFrame в единый словарь с суммированными значениями?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, pandas, словари

Есть DataFrame, в котором один из столбцов имеет строковые значения.
В строке стоит словарь по типу `1:259, 2:400, 3:800, 4:1200, 5:800`.
В словаре зашифрованы оценки пользователей - 259 человек поставили 1, 400 - 2 и так далее.

Как можно просуммировать значения всех словарей, чтобы получить на выходе один словарь с ключами и суммой значений всех словарей?

Сначала разобрался с проблемой строкового типа данных:

```
dict_sample = ast.literal_eval(string_sample)
```

Этo возвращает словарь.

Потом, по логике, я создал пустой словарь - `{1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}`, и циклом прибавил ко всем значениям значения из тестового словаря (`dict_sample`).

Но тут получился затык, не понимаю, сделать эту же историю для всего столбца.

Пока пробовал написать функцию и применить ее через лямбду к каждому элементу, но что-то не выходит, падает с ошибкой `keyerror`.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, мы поправим

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "val": ["{1:100, 2:200, 3:300, 4:400, 5:500}", 
            "{1:111, 2:222, 3:333, 4:444, 5:555}"]
})

In [21]: df
Out[21]:
                                   val
0  {1:100, 2:200, 3:300, 4:400, 5:500}
1  {1:111, 2:222, 3:333, 4:444, 5:555}

In [22]: type(df.loc[0, "val"])
Out[22]: str
```

решение:

```
from ast import literal_eval

res = pd.DataFrame(df["val"].map(literal_eval).to_list()).sum().to_dict()
```

результат:

```
In [24]: res
Out[24]: {1: 211, 2: 422, 3: 633, 4: 844, 5: 1055}
```

---

решение пошагово:

парсим строки в словари:

```
In [26]: df["val"].map(literal_eval)
Out[26]:
0    {1: 100, 2: 200, 3: 300, 4: 400, 5: ...
1    {1: 111, 2: 222, 3: 333, 4: 444, 5: ...
Name: val, dtype: object
```

преобразуем столбец в список элементов:

```
In [28]: df["val"].map(literal_eval).to_list()
Out[28]:
[{1: 100, 2: 200, 3: 300, 4: 400, 5: 500},
 {1: 111, 2: 222, 3: 333, 4: 444, 5: 555}]
```

создаем развернутый DataFrame из списка, полученного на предыдущем шаге:

```
In [30]: pd.DataFrame(df["val"].map(literal_eval).to_list())
Out[30]:
     1    2    3    4    5
0  100  200  300  400  500
1  111  222  333  444  555
```

суммируем значения в столбцах фрейма, полученного на предыдущем шаге:

```
In [31]: pd.DataFrame(df["val"].map(literal_eval).to_list()).sum()
Out[31]:
1     211
2     422
3     633
4     844
5    1055
dtype: int64
```

преобразуем полученный результат в словарь:

```
In [32]: pd.DataFrame(df["val"].map(literal_eval).to_list()).sum().to_dict()
Out[32]: {1: 211, 2: 422, 3: 633, 4: 844, 5: 1055}
```